# jQuery input value not removing on page ready

Tags: jquery

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("input[type=search]").val('');
            })
```

HTML:

```
<input type="search" class="form-control input-xlarge input-lg input-inline" placeholder="" aria-controls="example">
```

Link:

http://vsss.co.in/Admin/index.php/GST/gst_list

Anyone can please help me why value not becoming blank when the page is ready. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by `type=search` ? I think its `type=text`

Comment: No dude type=search you can check on given link.

Comment: It's working in console. What error you are getting?

Comment: the input field IS blank when I load that page (and there's no "value" attribute in the code)

Comment: As seen in the fiddle, your code works perfectly. https://jsfiddle.net/2wjqodhn/

Comment: @Johannes once type xyz in search and then refresh the page you will understand what I want to say.

Comment: @RushabhShah In your example, you don't have any value specified. Therefore, it should already be blank by default? Also, don't get confused between the `placeholder` and `value`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fd8wk8kg/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Option1
  alert($("input[type=search]").val());
  $("input[type=search]").val("");

  //Option2
  alert($("#yourId").val());
  $("#yourId").val("");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("input[type=search]").val('');
            })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" class="form-control input-xlarge input-lg input-inline" placeholder="" aria-controls="example" value="Does it works?">
```